# How to aggregate hourly values into 24h-average means without timestamp

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I have 'mydata_hourly' with 3 station (actually more) and their hourly temperature values over one year. This gives me 8760 hourly measurements in one year. Now I want to have the same structure but with the (365) 24h-average means 'mydata_daily'.

I have tried something with a for loop, this didn't work out. I have heard something about an aggregate function. I found something with a timestamp, what I don't have unfortunately.

.

```
my_data_hourly <- structure(c(8.29, 7.96, 8.14, 7.27, 7.37, 7.3, 7.23, 7.53, 
7.98, 10.2, 12.39, 14.34, 14.87, 14.39, 12.54, 11.84, 10.3, 10.62, 
10.65, 10.56, 10.43, 10.35, 9.85, 9.12, 8.95, 8.82, 8.92, 9.33, 
9.44, 9.3, 9.15, 9.37, 9.54, 10.24, 12.13, 12.43, 12.65, 13, 
13.18, 13.58, 13.64, 13.75, 13.85, 13.94, 13.79, 13.84, 13.94, 
14.26, 24.93, 24.64, 23.67, 21.46, 21.33, 20.83, 21.12, 21.1, 
23.75, 25.39, 30.72, 30.71, 30.81, 30.92, 32.61, 32.37, 32.49, 
30.68, 30.23, 30.45, 28.1, 26.9, 25.09, 25.07, 24.59, 24.22, 
23.05, 22.21, 22.07, 21.6, 21.24, 21.22, 21.85, 24.87, 28.85, 
29.42, 30.82, 30.97, 31.32, 30.81, 30.83, 29.9, 30.01, 30.31, 
30, 27.91, 25.78, 25.88, 8.78, 8.47, 8.49, 7.65, 8.63, 9.02, 
9.02, 8.11, 7.63, 9.19, 11.25, 12.24, 13.62, 12.09, 10.6, 11.1, 
10.16, 10.44, 9.58, 10.04, 10.01, 10.23, 9.51, 9.2, 9.34, 9.6, 
9.4, 9.45, 9.36, 9.26, 9.3, 9.46, 9.58, 9.89, 10.6, 11.04, 12.1, 
12.61, 13.12, 13.47, 13.55, 13.51, 13.63, 13.84, 13.93, 14.17, 
13.97, 13.86), .Dim = c(48L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("station1", 
"station2", "station3")))
```

.

```
hourly_measure    Station1          Station2           Station3
[1,]              8.29             24.93              8.78
[2,]              7.96             24.64              8.47
[3,]              8.14             23.67              8.49
[4,]              7.27             21.46              7.65
[5,]              7.37             21.33              8.63
[6,]              7.30             20.83              9.02
[7,]              7.23             21.12              9.02
[8,]              7.53             21.10              8.11
[9,]              7.98             23.75              7.63
[10,]             10.20            25.39              9.19
[11,]             12.39            30.72             11.25
[12,]             14.34            30.71             12.24
[13,]             14.87            30.81             13.62
[14,]             14.39            30.92             12.09
[15,]             12.54            32.61             10.60
[16,]             11.84            32.37             11.10
[17,]             10.30            32.49             10.16
[18,]             10.62            30.68             10.44
[19,]             10.65            30.23              9.58
[20,]             10.56            30.45             10.04
[21,]             10.43            28.10             10.01
[22,]             10.35            26.90             10.23
[23,]              9.85            25.09              9.51
[24,]              9.12            25.07              9.20
[25,]              8.95            24.59              9.34
[26,]              8.82            24.22              9.60
[27,]              8.92            23.05              9.40
[28,]              9.33            22.21              9.45
[29,]              9.44            22.07              9.36
[30,]              9.30            21.60              9.26
[31,]              9.15            21.24              9.30
[32,]              9.37            21.22              9.46
[33,]              9.54            21.85              9.58
[34,]             10.24            24.87              9.89
[35,]             12.13            28.85             10.60
[36,]             12.43            29.42             11.04
[37,]             12.65            30.82             12.10
[38,]             13.00            30.97             12.61
[39,]             13.18            31.32             13.12
[40,]             13.58            30.81             13.47
[41,]             13.64            30.83             13.55
[42,]             13.75            29.90             13.51
[43,]             13.85            30.01             13.63
[44,]             13.94            30.31             13.84
[45,]             13.79            30.00             13.93
[46,]             13.84            27.91             14.17
[47,]             13.94            25.78             13.97
[48,]             14.26            25.88             13.86
```

So in theory I want to have mydata_hourly[1:24,1] in my_data_daily[1,1]
and mydata_hourly[25:48,1] in mydata_daily[2,1]

Comment: "I have tried something with a for loop" please share the code with the for-loop!

Comment: You can create a grouping variable first, then use `aggregate` and friends. `your_data[, "grp"] <- rep(1:24, length.out = 24*365)`

Comment: A tangential comment: Before you calculate daily means, I'd suggest you run some checks on your data to root out anomalies that could skew your estimates. For example, row 38 for Station 2 looks erroneous – a 30° drop in an otherwise smooth time series. (That said, I'm not familiar with your system.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Lyngbakr . I accidentally deleted the 3 of 30. Now it is cleaned.

Comment: @markus Thank you. Your code did not quite solved my problem, but I appreciate your effort. `grp <- rep(1:365, each = 24)` is another possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are time series and it is probably best to use time series representations for them which will facilitate plotting and other time series processing.

**I) ts** Suppose your data is the matrix `m` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.  Convert that to a `ts` time series with frequency 24 and then aggregate it as shown.  No packages are used.

```
tt <- ts(m, frequency = 24)
aggregate(tt, 1, mean)
```

giving:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 2 
Frequency = 1 
  Station1 Station2  Station3
1 10.06333 26.89042  9.794167
2 11.71000 25.40542 11.585000
```

**2) zooreg** An alternative is to create zooreg objects using the zoo package.

```
library(zoo)

z <- zooreg(m, frequency = 24)
aggregate(z, as.integer, mean)
```

giving:

```
  Station1 Station2  Station3
1 10.06333 26.89042  9.794167
2 11.71000 25.40542 11.585000
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Station1          Station2           Station3
8.29             24.93              8.78
7.96             24.64              8.47
8.14             23.67              8.49
7.27             21.46              7.65
7.37             21.33              8.63
7.30             20.83              9.02
7.23             21.12              9.02
7.53             21.10              8.11
7.98             23.75              7.63
10.20            25.39              9.19
12.39            30.72             11.25
14.34            30.71             12.24
14.87            30.81             13.62
14.39            30.92             12.09
12.54            32.61             10.60
11.84            32.37             11.10
10.30            32.49             10.16
10.62            30.68             10.44
10.65            30.23              9.58
10.56            30.45             10.04
10.43            28.10             10.01
10.35            26.90             10.23
 9.85            25.09              9.51
 9.12            25.07              9.20
 8.95            24.59              9.34
 8.82            24.22              9.60
 8.92            23.05              9.40
 9.33            22.21              9.45
 9.44            22.07              9.36
 9.30            21.60              9.26
 9.15            21.24              9.30
 9.37            21.22              9.46
 9.54            21.85              9.58
10.24            24.87              9.89
12.13            28.85             10.60
12.43            29.42             11.04
12.65            30.82             12.10
13.00             0.97             12.61
13.18            31.32             13.12
13.58            30.81             13.47
13.64            30.83             13.55
13.75            29.90             13.51
13.85            30.01             13.63
13.94            30.31             13.84
13.79            30.00             13.93
13.84            27.91             14.17
13.94            25.78             13.97
14.26            25.88             13.86"
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @G.Grothendieck for your help. I tried **1)**. Very short but effective code.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Period = gl(n()/24, 24)) %>%
 summarise_at(-1, mean)

  Period Station1 Station2 Station3
  <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 1          10.1     26.9     9.79
2 2          11.7     25.4    11.6
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I tried the code but maybe I made a mistake somewhere. Did not quite work for my data. But interesting way.